# How to build a responsive Web Application - Design

Tags: html, web-applications, responsive-design, frameworks, software-design

I have little experience in building web applications. Now I have to build a web application which is responsive and accessible. I have to use an own with a Delphi build simple web server which can manage sessions via session cookies and react to AJAX queries. This is something I can't change, I have to use this server and have no access to Frameworks like PHP and so on.

Now I have several very basic questions how to build up the web application.

What I need:

1. On the starting page, there is only a header and a login
2. After the login, there is a new site with a small to header a menu and changing content where you load can load data, edit it, save, delete and so on. Like a real Desktop Application. Logout.
3. The data the user enters must sometimes be transferred between the different work pages.

What I know:

1. I need a Framework to simplify the responsive design. Bootstrap!?
2. I know how to use JavaScript with jQuery and basic CSS and basic HTML but don't know well if there are other Frameworks which simply other tasks. I'm I should use a UI Framework too. Maybe there is more
3. Is there a framework or something that support Accessibility?

What I don't know:

1. How do I build up the Application the right way. I mean is it common to duplicate some HTML code? eq. There is one header and one menu and changing working content, the header never changes, the menu only highlight the actual site, only the working area change. If I have to change the working content via the menu, is it common to include in each site the same header and slightly changed menu? I mean the browser has to load all content again... I looked at some websites and it look like this is the common way. Is that right?
2. If there are things like the header or formulas and so on, who are really never change, is there a way to include this HTML code/page "Inline" in other websites? If yes how
3. How to transfer the data between the pages? Not using Url-Parameters. I guess there is a HTML 5 Standard? Web Storage?
4. If I'm not forced to use a simple Delphi Server, what kind of Framework or Software you would advice me to use for this project?
5. I'm open to all advice, links to examples and so on

Answer (score 1):

Well no one can teach you how to build web applications over one answer. You can get started with bootstrap here:

- [getbootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)
- [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp)

Accessibility is another thing. You may need to read this topic separately. -> [Accessibility: Get Started](https://www.w3.org/WAI/fundamentals/accessibility-intro/)

Comment: You must also choose a server side platform like NodeJS or PHP. This is crucial to designing for web.

Comment: I can't choose the server side plattform, its a own webserver. Question "What I don't know, 1" is very important to know for me

Comment: Well that is why I'm telling you about server side. If you had PHP for example, you could add the header file in every page and no need to copy it every time. When you are on only HTML, you should check for a JavaScript solution. In general it is a very bad practice to have copy-pasted code everywhere.